What is the origin of the phrase "the world is on fire"?
I'm writing a historical novel set in the mid to late 1800s in the United States and wondering whether I can have one of the characters say that "the world is on fire." Meaning that everything is going to hell in a handbasket.
I did a search on Google's Ngram viewer, but it didn't bring up what you found Andy. This is what I used: "world is on fire","the world is on fire". This was the result: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22world+is+on+fire%22%2C+%22the+world+is+on+fire%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3
Obviously I did something wrong! Thanks for your help. Jody

If you've done any investigation yourself already, please edit to discuss it. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=world+is+on+fire&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

You can follow up by checking the Ngram quotes (don’t use quote marks). But my guess is that the words at that time would be taken as a reference to Armageddon.

You just need to remove your quote marks. Ngrams queries play by different rules than Google proper and many others; they're not at all "fuzzy" by default and are treated as full phrases..

If you are a writer, you have to decide. Personally, I think this works but this is an opinion question, which is not really allowed here.

I would question whether "'the world is on fire,' meaning that everything is going to hell in a handbasket," is even a common usage today. Recent uses in Google Books seem to be either apocalyptic metaphors, or a sense of “fiery” social controversy, as in the title Teaching While the World is on Fire, rather than an assessment of societal quality or health.
It puts me in mind of the idiomatic usages "trash fire" or "dumpster fire" for any calamitous, disgusting failure that "burns" out of control and would be impossible or messy to "put out." Looking at these two, "trash fire" seems to appear in the early 20th century (probably because large municipal "dumps" were rare before then), and "dumpster fire" grows like its referent starting ca. 2012.

The proposed "world is on fire" usage seems like an attempt to remove the anachronistic elements from these but preserve the intent. Browsing through the first page of results from 1850-1900, we find several fire-and-brimstone sermons referencing divine judgement and one colorful account of the aurora borealis and one of a meteor shower.
The only result that seems to be making a statement about current social dynamics is in a letter from Leo Tolstoy to Adin Ballou, discussing the latter's doctrine of "Christian non-resistance", which inspired Tolstoy who in turn inspired Gandhi.

"I am come to send fire on the earth, and what will I, if it be already kindled?" I think that this time is coming, and that the world is on fire, and our business is only to keep ourselves burning; and if we can communicate with other burning points, that is the work which I intend to do for the rest of my life.

Given the socio-political context of the correspondence, Tolstoy does seem  be using "the world is on fire" as a statement about current events, but his exact implication is unclear to me, and if anything, the metaphor seems to be a positive one, about spreading an influence for change.

Incidentally, the expression "going to hell in a handbasket" also seems to be a 20th century usage.
There are a couple of earlier instances that hint at an earlier tradition of "going to hell in" other containers, but they are so few that it might be coincidence. Many are re-references to an 1828 description of Fairfield Church, built in 1493 specifically to house a set of painted windows designed by Albrecht Dürer and seemingly seized piratically by an Englishman while bound for Rome. One window apparently includes "a woman going to hell in a wheelbarrow for scolding her husband."
This 15th-century bit of iconography seems tantalizingly close to the other modern alliterative variant, "going to hell in a handcart," but I can find only one 19th-century instance of the phrase, in a waggishly moralizing column originally appearing in the New York Sunday Mercury some time before being gathered and published in book form in 1841: [Some sluggards] "would rather ride to hell in a hand-cart than walk to heaven supported by the staff of industry."
The other remaining instance is a short humorous anecdote about unsolicited proselytizing on a passenger boat, under the headline "Going to hell in a canal-boat" ("'Well,' said the pious man, 'you must surely be going to hell.' 'That cannot be,' said a lady, 'as this boat goes no further than Whitehall.'")

'the world is on fire' in the seventeenth century
Early English Books Online, a database of publications form the period 1475 to 1700, reports 12 unique matches for the phrase "the world is on fire." All of these instances appear in religious works, and most seem either explicitly or figuratively to invoke the Last Judgment as described in the Bible.
Here are the earliest seven examples, starting with Arthur Lake, "The Tenth Sermon: Exodus 19, Verse 16," in Ten Sermons Deliuered on the Nineteenth Chapter of Exodus, Contayning the Preface of God, and the Preparation of the People to the Promulgation of the Law (1629):

And indeed, after God hath made vs sensible of our weaknesse, and his greatnesse; he vseth to support and strengthen his children, he makes them experience the truth of that answere which Christ gaue to Saint Paul, My grace is sufficient for thee, my strength is made perfect in weaknesse 2. Cor. 12. vers. 9. So did he hearten Esay with a cole from the Altar, Daniel with a touch, Moses with an answere, a kind answere, and by Moses he bid the Israelites not feare. And what wonder if he support his children in these tremblings, seeing he supported the Hill? for other wise the hil being al on fire & trembling in the fire must needs haue bin consumed, but it held out. Yea and so did Moses & Aaron when they entred into the cloud, & trod vpon that fierie hil, no lesse securely then the three children did in the fierie Furnace, whereinto they were cast by the appointment of Nebuchadnezzar. * 1.298 And so shall the righteous at the day of iudgement, when all the world is on fire, and a lowder Trumpet shal sound then this description at mount Sinai. And wee must repute it a singular priuiledge of the children of God, that they can subsist in such a place, and such a presence.

From Robert Bolton, "Of Death," in Mr. Bolton's Last and Learned Worke of the Four Last Things, Death, Iudgement, Hell, and Heaven (1632):

If the LORD should let loose the cord of thy conscience, and set His just and deserved wrath a worke to enkindle flames of horrour in thy heart, what helpe couldest thou have in heapes of gold, or hoards of wealth? Remember Spira. They would be so farre from healing the wound, or allaying the smart, that they would yet more horribly afflict thy already enraged spirit, and turne them even into fiery Scorpions for thy further torment. Let thy last sicknesse seize upon thee, and then say (for the houre of death, as they say, is the houre of truth) whether all the gold and goods in the world can any more deliver thee from the Arrest of that inexorable Serjeant, than can an handfull of dust? Nay, whether then the extremity of thy spirituall affliction, and anguish of soule, will not be answerable to the former excesse of thine inordinate affection to earthly things, and delights of sense? Or suppose thou shouldest be surprized description by that last and great day, which the LORD in mercy hasten; how wilt thou then rescue thy free-hold, when the whole frame of the world is on fire?

From Thomas Adams, A Commentary or, Exposition vpon the Diuine Second Epistle Generall, Written by the Blessed Apostle St. Peter (1633):

The tongue is a fire, that fireth the whole course of nature, and is fired of hell. Let them whose mouthes flame with oaths, feare these flaming torments. The rich man's tongue was tormented in fire, because it was used to spit fire against heaven. Drunkennesse is a burning sinne: too much wine is the oile of hells owne Lampe. They inflame the reckoning, till they inflame their braines, inflame their blouds, inflame their bodies: buy as much sicknesse, as will make up a burning fever; and as much sinne as will serve to inflame their owne hell. In the German proverbe, Fire is of all the genders. Hic ignis, that's fire: Haec ignis, that's an whore: Hoc ignis, that's wine. the first Chapter of Iohn Verse 5. Mundus positus est in maligno, that is in igne malo: all the world is on fire with sin, to make worke for the fire of hell.

From Samuel Bolton, A Tossed Ship Making to Safe Harbor, or, A Word in Season to a Sinking Kingdome Wherein Englands Case and Cure, Her Burthens and Comforts, Her Pressures and Duties Are Opened and Applyed (1644):

A fourth time, and that is at the day of judgement, when Heaven and Earth and all the world is on fire then shall Christ appeare as a Ghost indeed full of terror to every wicked and ungodly person. We reade, that the wicked at that day, shall call upon the mountaines to fall upon them, to hide them from the face of him that sitteth on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lambe, for the day of wrath is come, and who shall be able to beare it? In their thoughts, they were better able to beare the weight of Rocks, of Mountains on them, then the sight of Christ: so terrible will Christ appeare to ungodly men at that great day.

From Nicholas Lockyer, England Faithfully Watcht With, in her Wounds: or, Christ as a Father Sitting Up with his Children in Their Swooning State (1646):

Strife is common now, all the world is on fire; but tis so voyd of divine property, that I know not what will become of us all; tis hell fire that burnes onely to torment persons, and aug∣ment sinnes; such is our lung and tongue contests at this day; as for other fights (the Lord be gracious to us) they are very bloody, but what their nature is otherwise, I am unskild to speake: heart fight makes hand fight; love was slaine before our wars began, or we had never gone together by the eares with any weapon, neither with tongue nor hand. Justice hath found us out, and turnd our inside outwards; what will be in the end God knowes; if the Spirit of Christ be wanting in contention, tis the saddest worke in the world, and of the most desperate issue, and yet nothing puts upon greater temptation this way.

From Anthony Farindon, "The Nineteenth Sermon," in XXX sermons lately preached at the parish church of Saint Mary Magdalen Milkstreet, London (1647):

And that we may better understand it, we must sever it from that which is like it; for likenesse is the mother of error, from whence it is, that there be so many lovers of peace, and so little of it in the world; that when ambition and covertousnesse harrass the earth, when there be warrs and rumours of warrs, when the kings of the earth rise up, when the people are as mad as the Sea when it rageth, when the world is on fire, yet there is not one that will be convinced, or perswade himself, that he ever raised one spark to kindle it. It was a just and grave complaint of Saint Hierom, non reddimus unicui{que} rei suum vocabulum, we are guilty of a dangerous misnomer, and do not give every thing its proper name; and think we study quietnesse when we are most bent to war, and ready to beat up the drumme. Alii Dominationem pacem appellant, some call tyranny peace, and nothing else, and think there is no peace, unlesse every man understand and obey their beck; unlesse all hands subscribe to their unwarrantable demands; quiet they are and peaceable men, when like a tempest they drive down all before them; to him that tyrannizeth in the common-wealth, he is rebell that is not a parasite; and to him that Lords it in the Church, he that bows not to every decree of his, as if God himself had made it, is an heretick, a schismatick, an Anathema; then this peace, and not till then, when every look, and word, when every lye of theirs is a law.

And from Jeremy Taylor, "Sermon XXV: The Miracles of the Divine Mercy," in XXVIII Sermons Preached at Golden Grove Being for the Summer Half-Year, Beginning on Whit-Sunday, and Ending on the XXV Sunday After Trinity (1651/1654):

But then for the other part of the severe law and laborious imposition, that we must work out our spiritual interest with the labours of our spirit, seems to most men to be so intolerable, that rather then passe under it they quit their hopes of heaven, and passe into the portion of Devils; and what can there be to alleviate this sorrow, that a man shall be perpetually sollicited with an impure tempter, and shall carry a flame within him, and all the world is on fire round about him, and every thing brings fuel to the flame, and full tables are a snare, and empty tables are collateral servants to a lust, and help to blow the fire and kindle the heap of prepared temptations, and yet a man must not at all tast of the forbidden fruit, and he must not desire what he cannot choose but desire, and he must not enjoy whatsoever he does violently covet, and must never satisfy his appetite in the most violent importunities, but must therefore deny himself, because to do so is extremely troublesome; this seems to be an art of torture and a devise to punish man with the spirit of agony, and a restlesse vexation.

There are also four instances in the EEBO database of the phrase "the whole world is in fire." Again, all four appear in religious texts, two of them in Thomas Adams's 1633 Commentary, already cited above. The two non-Adams instances refer specifically to the destruction of Sodom.

'the world is on fire' in the latter half of the nineteenth century
A Google Books search for the phrase "the world is on fire" for the period 1857 to 1900 yields dozens of unique matches, along with a large number of duplicates. Some of these instances involve astronomical phenomena such as aurora borealis or meteor showers or dawn, but many others arise in the context of religious works, including a healthy (or unhealthy) number that invoke the Last Judgment. Still others use the expression more generally and metaphorically, as in this instance from "Holiness" in The Advocate of Christian Holiness (April 1877):

Holiness now ; holiness forever ;—now is the time, the set time, the important, the momentous! All nature, all grace,—the heavens above, the earth beneath,—with united voice cry out thunderingly : "Be ye holy, for I am holy." The present crisis is a crisis fraught immensely with things unheard of. The world is on fire! If ever holiness to the Lord, the presenting the body with all its powers, a living sacrifice, a whole burnt-offering, was needed, it is now!

The Advocate of Christian Holiness was published in Boston, Massachusetts. This excerpt does have an apocalyptic (not to say hysterical) tone, but it seems to be using the phrase "The world is on fire!" to convey the idea that the humanity (in 1877) is in a state of profound moral and political crisis—not to indicate that the Last Judgment is imminent.
Another interesting example uses this expression in the context of alcohol consumption and the temperance movement. From Watson Vaughan, "Shall We Fail?" in The National Temperance Orator (London, 1874):

Methinks I hear the cry of fire! fire! rolling from the sultry belt to either pole. The world is on fire! burning up with the liquid fire—more terrific in its march than the Chicago flames! The cold-water army is on its march to extinguish the fire. If we succeed, we will proclaim a year of Jubilee—the world redeemed from the curse of dissipation.

In any event, I don't think that the expression "The world is on fire" would seem anachronistic if used figuratively by a character in a novel set in the United States in the late nineteenth century.
